# Close vote options will never load if I've already cast a close vote on the question

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, android-app

In the Android App, if I open the close dialog for a question that I've [already voted to close](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RzyIA.png), the close options will simply be stuck loading forever.

This initially came up in version 1.0.26 on Android 4.4.2, and it's still present in version 1.0.49 on Android 4.4.3, both on a HTC One.

If I've already voted to close, I will never be presented with the close options, nor will I even be informed I've already cast a close vote previously, I'll just see the loading spinner indefinitely. When this happens, I have to wait for a while wondering if my 'net is being slow, or if I've already voted to close this question.

Here they are, loading:

[image: and I'm patiently waiting]

And here they are, *still* loading, a few minutes later:

[image: at least I have this loading spinner to keep me company]

Comment: I have seen this happen on my Galaxy S3 also.

Comment: Confirmed on Moto X with Android 4.4.4.

Comment: This is still happening on 1.0.52