# Takes forever to close on Android

Tags: bug, vote-to-close, android-app

When I try to vote to close on Android, a box pops up to show the close reasons, and then the wait cursor starts to circle and stays that way for over a minute.

Comment: Any chance you already voted to close the question in the past? See [this other report](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226788/close-options-load-forever-if-ive-already-voted-to-close-a-question), maybe you voted long time ago and it's expired, check in the desktop site.

Comment: Absolutely not.

Comment: So I fear we'll have to wait for a dev to go check. Is it still happening?

Comment: Unpredictably..

Comment: Happens to me, not a minute, but much longer than it takes to open questions or the feed, or just about anything else.